# Excel concatenate function with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have the following in my first 3 columns of my sheet in excel:

Results table. C3 is where I want the concatenation done

[image]

I also have the following table:

[image: Table 69]

Now I am trying to use concatenate to retrieve the items from table 69 using the following conditions:
Spec = the value in B1 (Yellow in first photo)
Slot = each of the values in column A (A2:A18)

this is the formula I have in C2:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(AND(Table69[Spec]=$B$1;Table69[Slot]=A2);Table69[Item];"")& ",")
```

Can anybody help me with this as this formula for the moment is returning as if there was no values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer using Text join.

Thank you all that took the time.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF((Table69[Spec]=$B$1)*(Table69[Slot]=A2);Table69[Item];""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using commas instead of semicolons. Once you do that your formula should return "Icon of the Silver Crescent,".

As a side note, the ampersand "&" sign will do the same thing as the concatenate formula. You are adding a comma at the end of your function.

Comment: My excel is European so all formulas are written with semicolons. That is not the issue of the formula. The goal of the formula is to have as many values as possible separated with a comma, the reason I put the & at the end